# How to hide portlet icon and title but keep edit controls in Liferay?

Tags: java, css, liferay

How to hide portlet icon and title but keep edit controls in Liferay?

Most combinations of these styles didn't help:

```
.portlet-borderless-bar {
    display:none;
}

.portlet-topper {
    display: none
}

.portlet-title {
    display: none;
}
```

they are either remove everything or keep everything.

Comment: Which Liferay version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Using Liferay 6.2,

Just click the settings icon on the left and select look and feel from the drop down. Then under Portlet Configuration, select No for Show Borders.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.portlet-title-text, .portlet-title .icon {
        display: none;
}
.portlet-title {
        height: 15px;
}
```